# Proportional Bar Chart from Dataframe Created from Melt of Another Data Set

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I need to create a proportional bar chart from a data set created by using the melt function from dplyr. By proportional, I mean that I would need a chart for which the height of each bar would be different, based on the proportion of the total. I would like to proportion to be for the value X generated by the following sample code, with fill based on "group". I have tried many online solutions, and I constantly run into not an error code, but solid bars, with no difference in proportions

See sample code:

````
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(1)
example_matrix <-matrix(rpois(90,7), nrow=6,ncol=15)
example_df <- data.frame(example_matrix)
rownames(example_df) <-c('group1','group2','group3','group4','group5','group6')
df <- reshape2::melt(as.matrix(example_df))```
````

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
example_matrix <-matrix(rpois(90,7), nrow=6,ncol=15)
example_df <- data.frame(example_matrix)
rownames(example_df) <-c('group1','group2','group3','group4','group5','group6')
df <- reshape2::melt(as.matrix(example_df))
df$fraction <- df$value/sum(df$value)

setDT(df)

p <-
  ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Var2, y = fraction, fill = Var1)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "red", "black", "orange", "pink", "yellow"))

print(p)
```

Comment: This almost works. It seems like the denominator fails to group by the categories in Var2, leading to distortedly small proportions. How could I fix this?

Comment: you need to set position = "dodge" in the bar plot, I have updated the answer. try once.

Comment: Also, sorry, one problem I have run into is that I have had to set the denominator for df$fraction to be a fixed value, not from the sum of the values. Your fix addresses the skewed values, done the other way, but what I try to accommodate the fixed value for the denominator and the  new grouping (see below), the proportions are correct, but the fill doesn't function properly. What do you advise
 
```
new_df_col <- df %>% group_by(Var2) %>% 
  mutate(denom_df_group = sum(value))
n_fix =300
df$fraction <- as.numeric((df$denom_df_group)/n_fix)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done with the plotting commands directly, you'll need to transform your data before. For example:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% group_by(Var2) %>% mutate(fraction = value/sum(value))
```

and then plot either with the `ggplot` solution from the other answer or here's a `plotly` version:

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(data = df, x = ~Var2, y = ~fraction, color = ~Var1, type = 'bar')
```